# Как загрузить PKCS#12 контейнер с ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012 ключом через BouncyCastle в Java?

Tags: java, криптография, pkcs#12, bouncycastle

Для подписывания запросов к серверу с помощью ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012 мне нужно получить из PKCS#12 контейнера ключ и сертификат с помощью BouncyCastle.

Есть PKCS#12 контейнер, сгенерированный следующим образом:

```
openssl req -newkey gost2012_256 -pkeyopt paramset:A  -passout pass:test -keyout test.key -out test.crt -x509 -days 3650 
openssl pkcs12 -export -in test.crt -inkey test.key -out container.p12 -password pass:test -passin pass:test
```

Есть следующий код:

```
public class BouncyCastleGostTest {

    static {
        BouncyCastleProvider bcProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        String name = bcProvider.getName();
        Security.removeProvider(name); 
        Security.addProvider(bcProvider);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final File file = new File("/tmp/container.p12");

        final byte[] keyStoreData = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

        final String password = "test";
        final String keyPassword = "test";

        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");

        try (ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyStoreData)) {
            keyStore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
        }

        final String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
        keyStore.getKey(alias, keyPassword.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Однако этот код выдаёт ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key encoding.
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.unwrapKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at BouncyCastleGostTest.main(BouncyCastleGostTest.java:31)
    ... 5 more
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы это заработало? Контейнер с RSA ключом открывается без проблем. Пробовал ГОСТ 2012 и 2001, а также разную битность. Результат один и тот же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в версии OpenSSL. На момент создания вопроса BouncyCastle не умел открывать подобные контейнеры.

Заработает с версии 1.65.

Github: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/675